# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I havent been able to figure out what the problem is here. I am using vue 3.
I trye to add an obejct to another object inside of the store state. I can add it to the firebase console, but the only thing that has not been solved yet is how to add it to the store in the `state.coaches` as an object within an object. In this way I would be able to display the list of object into the view of the screen.

```js
//store-coach.js
import Vue from 'vuex'
import { uid, Notify } from 'quasar'
import firebase from 'boot/firebase'

const state = {
  coaches: {
  }
}

const mutations = {
  addCoach(state, coach) {
    Vue.set(state.coaches, coach.id, coach.coach)
    }
}

const actions = {
  fbReadDataCoaches({ commit }) {
    let coachesfb = firebase.database().ref('coaches')
    //child added
    coachesfb.on('child_added',snapshot => {
      let coachfb = snapshot.val()
      let payload = {
        id: snapshot.key,
        coach: coachfb
      }
      commit('addCoach', payload)
    })
  },
  fbaddCoach({}, payload){
    let coachRef = firebase.database().ref('coaches/' + payload.id)
    coachRef.set(payload.coach, error =>{
      if(!error){
        Notify.create('Coach added!!')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```js
//index.js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import coaches from './store-coach'
export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      coaches
    }
  })
  return Store
}
```

The error that I get is when
`Vue.set(state.coaches, coach.id, coach.coach)` is fired

```
Uncaught TypeError: vuex__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.set is not a function
```

thanks in advance!
Appreciate your time!

Comment: is that actually a `Vue` static method?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In first file (store-coach.js), change:-

From -

```
import Vue from 'vuex'
```

To -

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

As `.set` method is available in vue package. Its not available in vuex package that is why you are getting this error. [Documentation reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: The suggested answer implements vuejs2, however, the code wont work since the code is implemented with vuejs3